# Trying to return an array with stored elements (java)

Tags: java, arrays, storage

I am trying to store a set of numbers into an array with a for loop condition followed by if condition, and this method should return the array with stored elements respecting the conditional statement. I have been stuck in this problem for a while, but nothing is coming to my mind.

```
public int [] method ( int a) {
    int [] newarray=new int[count];

    for (int i=1; i<=a; i++)  {
        If (a%i==0) {
            for (int m=0; m<count;m++) {        
               newarray[m]=a/i;
               break;
            }
        }
    }
    return newarray;
}
```

Comment: Please, format your code and resolve compiler error.

Comment: for (int m=0; m    What does it mean?

Comment: Quickest would be to add to a List<integer>  , convert to array after the loop.

Comment: Public -> public. newarray -> newarray[m] ?. semicolon after `int[count]`...

Comment: You have to add an index for the array: newarray[m]=a/i;

Comment: Even if you add index for newarray assignment as `newarray[m]=a/i` your array will be overwritten. What is the exact requirement here?

Comment: what error you are getting? where is 'count' initialized?

Comment: You say `I have been stuck in this problem` yet you do not present the actual problem. How are we to determine what you are trying to achieve with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int [] method (int a) {
    int [] newarray = new int[count];

    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)  {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            for (int m = 0; m < count; m++) {        
                if (newarray[m] == 0) {
                   newarray[m] = a/i;
                   break;
                }
            }

            break;//Depending on your wanted solution
        }
    }

    return newarray;
}
```

I've assumed that whenever an array-index contains a 0 it's uninitialized, and is considered empty.

In your original code, the second for-loop would overwrite the first index in the array every time. The if-statement I've added ensures that it only adds a number in an available slot.

I've also added a second break; Since you have two for-loops you need two breaks to completely get out of the loops. I didn't understand from your question whether or not this was something you wished for. Therefore, you have to decide whether or not to keep it in.

***Edit:***

Let's say this your array `newarray` when `count == 10`

```
0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

This is what happens in you second for-loop:

```
for (int m = 0; m < count; m++) {        
    newarray[m] = a/i;
    break;
}
```

First time in the loop is when `m == 0` and so the lines that are executed are

```
newarray[0] = a/i;
break;
```

Then, because of the `break;` the program will exit the loop. What value `a/i` varies, but in this example, let's say `a/i` is 8. Therefore, `newarray` now looks like this:

```
8   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Next time your program enters the second for-loop the exact same thing will happen. If `a/i` at that time is, let's say, 3, then we'll get

```
newarray[0] = 3;
break;
```

and your array will now look like this

```
3   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0
```

As you can see, everytime your code runs, the first index will get overwritten. The if-statement I put in makes sure that it doesn't overwrite unless the array-slot equals 0(since that means it's empty).

With the extra if-statement

```
for (int m = 0; m < count; m++) {        
    if (newarray[m] == 0) {
        newarray[m] = a/i;
        break;
    }
}
```

the first time around `m == 0`

newarray[0] is not equal to 0. (from last time: newarray[0] is 3)

therefore the code continues to `m == 1`

newarray[1] is equal to 0 and then

```
newarray[1] = a/i;
break;
```

is executed.

Hope that makes sense. Notice that there is a downside doing this. If `a/i` ever is 0, it will just get overwritten next time your loop runs.

Comment: It worked, can you explain me the logic behind the extra if statement.

Answer (score 0):

From you code i presume you need and array containing `count` repeatition of elements of divisor of a variable. Eg if count is 5 and a is 10 you need an array like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]`

If this is the case try

```
public int[] method(int a) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=1; i<=a; i++)  {
        if(a%i==0) {
            int value = a/i;
            for (int m=0; m<count; m++) {        
                list.add(value);
            }
        }
    }
    int[] newArray = new int[list.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for(Integer i : list){
        newArray[index++] = i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(newArray);
    return newArray;
}
```